# Backup Mysql Via a Button Click in Java Jsp Servlet Application

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, dump

i want to set a button in my front end and after the click that button i want to backup my MySQL database and download the SQL file. really is there a way to perform this task.thank you.

```
Process p = null;
        try {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            p = runtime.exec("mysqldump -u dinmarkh_root -pushanlac absdfer_bldb > /home/abcd/a.com/back.bcdsql");
            InputStream inputStream = p.getInputStream();
            ServletOutputStream strm = resp.getOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                strm.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            strm.close();
            int processComplete = p.waitFor();
            if (processComplete == 0) {
                System.out.println("Backup created successfully!");
            } else {
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: There are quite a couple of different points here. Best to have a cron backup job after midnight to a yyyyMMddHHmmss.bcdsql.gz file, and provide access via SFTP or such.

Comment: how to do that can you explain please...

Comment: Sorry (weekend), You best search on the internet for such things.